# how does one get native 2-body measurements?

Tags: quantum-gate, measurement, error-correction, error-mitigation

How are Majorana-based architectures able to possess native 2-body measurement operations? Could anyone provide an appropriate reference explaining that?
Are those native measurement operations expected to be much better in performance compared to the circuit that uses a CNOT with an ancillary and measures the ancillary for doing 2-body measurements?

Comment: There is a recently published paper that explains native 2-body measurement in detail, including a practical example. You can check it out here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.08849. Generally speaking, errors propagate at each step of the circuit. For example, in a two-body parity check circuit, there are two CNOT gates (plus two Hadamard gates if it is an XX parity check circuit), and errors accumulate on these gates throughout the circuit. However, in native 2-body measurement, there is no place for errors to accumulate. Whether it is efficient or not depends on your implementation (your pulse)